# Neo4j (cypher-shell) Create relationship too slow for existing nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, cypher-shell

I'm struggling to create relationships among existing nodes in Neo4j (v.4.1.1). I'm creating nodes and edges via cypher-shell and a text file containing cypher commands. First I created around 20K nodes. Cypher-shell ran without issues. But then when trying to connect nodes with another script, cypher-shell freezes or hangs without giving any information about its progress. The script to create (bi-directional) connections consists of 2 parts: one in which I match nodes, and another in which I create the corresponding connections. I also created an index on a node property called "image_id" beforehand.

An example of a command to create a node in the first script looks like this:

`-- create_nodes.txt:`

`CREATE (i_20040:Image {image_id: 'MDteiLH1CZY', image_name: 'SetA_MDteiLH1CZY.jpg', cluster: 99})`

whereas an example to create connections looks like this:

`-- create_edges.txt:`

(from the matching section)
`MATCH (node_0: Image {image_id: '-kBXeZqJtMY'})`

(and then from the connecting section)
`MERGE (node_0)-[:IS_SIMILAR]->(node_1) MERGE (node_1)-[:IS_SIMILAR]->(node_0)`

There are around 40K connections to create. I'm running cypher-shell from the terminal in Neo4j desktop (Windows 10) like this:

`> cypher-shell -f create_edges.txt`

I would appreciate any hints on what I am missing or doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Definitely add an index on image id property

Comment: I have done that already but I see no change. :(